# Comparing two integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [1,\infty)$ be Lebesgue measurable. Which quantity is greater:
>
> > $\int_0^1 \! f(x)\log f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$
> >
> > or
> >
> > $\int_0^1 \! f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \int_0^1 \! \log f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z.  $

I was thinking of using Fubini-Tonelli in some way, but I am not getting anywhere. I would be very grateful for some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did originally posted this answer, with a small omission, but changed to another. I think it is worth having this answer, so I will repeat it.

The function $u(x)=x\log(x)$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$: $u''(x)=\frac1x\gt0$.

By Jensen's Inequality, we have
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\cdot\log\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right) \le\int_0^1f(x)\log(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Furthermore, since $\log(x)$ is concave on $(0,\infty)$ we have
$$
\int_0^1\log(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\le\log\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag{2}
$$
Since $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\ge0$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\cdot\int_0^1\log(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
\le\int_0^1f(x)\log(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The functions $u:x\mapsto x$ and $v:x\mapsto\log x$ are both nondecreasing on $[1,+\infty)$ hence they are *positively associated*. Thus, for every function $f$ with values in $[1,+\infty)$,
$$\int_0^1u(f)\cdot\int_0^1v(f)\leqslant\int_0^1u(f)v(f).
$$
The simplest approach to prove this might be to expand the LHS of the inequality
$$
\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1\left[u(f(x))-u(f(y))\right]\cdot\left[v(f(x))-v(f(y))\right]\cdot\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\geqslant0.
$$

Comment: You get
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\log\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right) \le\int_0^1f(x)\log(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
You should also note that $\log$ is concave on $(0,+\infty)$, so that
$$
\int_0^1\log(f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\le\log\left(\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)
$$

Comment: @robjohn You are quite right, sorry about this. See modified version. (If in the mood, add here some considerations about the hasty acceptations of answers--definitely a plague of the site.)

Comment: This is a good answer, too. (+1) However, I think your previous answer, with a small fix, is good, too. I hope you don't mind that I repeated it.

Comment: Do you have a good link for positive association? I assume it means something like $(u(x)-u(y))(v(x)-v(y))\ge0$.

Comment: @robjohn For this, one could look into some literature about coupling methods.